# OnTouchEvent method overlap setOnItemLongClickListener in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I created a custom `expandableListView` (extends of `ExpandableListView`). Now I need to override the `OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. But, I need use `setOnItemLongClickListener` for a child item too. But it does not work when `onTouchEvent` is overridden. When I use `onChildItemListener` too, then it works fine. Why does it happen, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the "normal" `OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` calls the required events of the children. Call `super.OnTouchEvent(event);` to fix it.